# Algorithm for locating the closest destination(s) to source(s) and resolving conflicts in case a single destination is mapped to multiple sources

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Problem Statement: Given a matrix of people(denoted by small alphabets) and bikes(denoted by capital alphabets), find the nearest bike for a given person.
How will you change your solution if you have to find bikes for a set of people? (assuming multiple bikes can be at the same distance from 1 person)?

I know [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Bellman Ford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm), but curious about the implementation here. Or can it be solved by [BFS(Breadth First Search)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)?

Comment: I think combinatorial search algorithms can also help like A* search.

Comment: @kiner_shah starting BFS from the bikes should locate the nearest biker. Not fully sure though. Following which, resolving conflicts seems to be another problem. I am thinking along the lines of topological sorting. Would be great if someone can confirm

Comment: Yeah, BFS can be used, Have you considered the case when there are >= 2 bikes at same distance available for a person. Also, among those bikes, only 1 bike is accessible to another person, so which bike will you choose for first person? For first question, BFS will easily work. For second question, not sure!

Comment: Backtracking may do the trick, for the second part of the question. Not sure though how to go about it. Any similar example or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the second part different from the first? I.e. what difference does it make that you consider your people as being represented by the set as opposed to lowercase letters? And can a given bike be assigned to multiple people?

Comment: @fuglede bikes are represented using capital alphabets to distinguish it from the people. A single bike can only be assigned to a person(and vice-versa). The second part concerns optimality of the solution in case multiple bikes are equidistant from a person

Comment: @AbhisekGhosh: And just to repeat jrook's question, what's your optimization objective in that case? The sum over all assignments? And are there more bikes than people?

Comment: The sum over the distances appearing in each assignment, that is.

Comment: Yes, the sum over all distances should be minimum

Answer (score 1):

To assign a single bike to a single person, you can use BFS or you can have a per-processing step in which you caclculate all the distances from people to bikes, store them, and use the table to answer single assignment queries.

It gets more complicated if you want to assign a group of bikes to a group of people. Then, you need to have an objective. For example, if your objective is to minimize total distance traveled by all the people to reach their assigned bikes, you are effectively solving a *minimum weight bipartite matching problem* which can be formulated and solved as a linear programming problem.

[These lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-notes.pdf) explain the problem and the algorithm.

Comment: The problem was asked in an interview for a fresher role. I think there might be an easier way to approach this. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Formulating an optimization problem is not the same as solving it. The idea that we should define an objective and formulate a problem is very basic. Maybe there is a way to convert it to a more straightforward algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing @jrook's answer, note that the "minimum weight full bipartite matching" ("full" or "perfect" because otherwise the optimal solution is the empty matching) also goes under the name of the *[linear assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)*, just to give some more keywords to get you started.

While it's certainly true that phrasing the problem as a linear programming problem does the job, indeed there are plenty of algorithms that provide solutions for this particular case.

If you're familiar with shortest path and augmenting path search algorithms (such as those that can be used to [maximum bipartite matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching) or [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow)), then perhaps the simplest algorithm to understand is what you first get by realizing that the problem at hand is a special case of the [minimum cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) which can be solved by replacing the BFS step of the Edmonds--Karp algorithm by a shortest path search. More common in introductory texts is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

If you care about performance, there are more efficient algorithms out there; indeed it is easy to find solutions that are [orders of magnitude faster](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/fuglede/d7bb1dcdf23669eacc7eef3256198789/raw/04d3551643f98c642589cf85dd9319c9605697f8/lap-benchmark.ipynb) than what you get by just throwing a commercial solver after the linear programming formulation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will check them out!