# How to solve this algorithmic problem - Gopher 2

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am trying to solve this problem https://open.kattis.com/problems/gopher2:

> The gopher family, having averted the canine threat, must face a new
>   predator.
>
> The are  gophers and  gopher holes, each at distinct (,)
>   coordinates. A hawk arrives and if a gopher does not reach a hole in
>    seconds it is vulnerable to being eaten. A hole can save at most
>   one gopher. All the gophers run at the same velocity . The gopher
>   family needs an escape strategy that minimizes the number of vulnerable > > gophers.

t minimizes the number of vulnerable gophers.

The brute force approach would be to find all possible holes reachable for each gopher, then find all distinct (gopher, hole) pairs.

Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: This can be formulated as a *minimum weight bipartite matching* problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306586/2928853) for some ideas about how to solve it.

Comment: @jrook How would you formulate it as a weighted graph problem? The goal is to maximise the number of gophers saved, not save them with the least walking time.

Answer (score 1):

This can be formulated as an instance of the [maximum cardinality matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching) on a bipartite graph.

Let `A` be the set of gophers and `B` be the set of holes. There is an edge from gopher `a ∈ A` to hole `b ∈ B` if the distance between them is at most `s*v`, i.e. the maximum distance a gopher can run in the available time.

A solution consists of a maximum-size subset of the edges in this graph, such that (1) each `a ∈ A` has at most one edge, (2) each `b ∈ B` has at most one edge. The constraints represent the rules that each gopher can only go to one hole, and each hole can only fit one gopher. The number of "vulnerable" gophers is then the number of gophers minus the number of edges in the matching.

The graph takes O(*mn*) time to construct, and a maximum cardinality matching can be found in O(*mn*) time or less using a standard algorithm such as [Ford–Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm), where *m* is the number of gophers and *n* is the number of holes.

If that isn't efficient enough for the online judge, you can use [a more efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms) to find the matching, and a more efficient way to find the edges in the graph, e.g. using a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to query which holes are within distance `s*v` of a gopher in under O(*n*) time.